# I'm having problems prototyping in .h files in C++ and defining them on a Cpp file

Tags: c++, prototype

I'm kinda new to stack overflow so let me know how I can improve my format for asking questions and displaying code.

My problem is that 
I keep getting a Linker error undefined reference to Father::Father() and undefined reference to Father::display()

Here is my code:

**Father.h**

```
#ifndef FATHER_H
#define FATHER_H
#include <iostream>

class Father
{
      public:
             Father();
             void display();


      private:



};

#endif
```

**Father.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Father.h"

Father::Father
{

}
void Father::display()
{

     std::cout << "I am your father" << std::endl;
}


/*
This is my enter code here

*/
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Father.h"



int main()
{
    Father Darth;
    Darth.display();


    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the syntax correction, I've changed it to Father::Father() and still have the linker errors

Comment: Do you compile `Test.cpp` and `Father.cpp` together?

Answer (score 0):

[Linking two .cpp and a .h files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032709/linking-two-cpp-and-a-h-files)

I just saw this as a possible solution, I'm thinking I'm having problems with linking H files with CPP files.